# Markov chains and biased coin

Tags: markov-chains

An unfair coin turns up heads with probability 0.2. It is tossed repeatedly. What is the expected number of tosses until there are two heads in a row?

How can one use Markov chains to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Since we know the probability of this coin turning up heads is `0.2`, the odds of getting two heads in a row at any point in time would be `0.2 * 0.2 = 0.04`.

Now let's ask the question: How many times would we need to flip the coin to reach an expected value of `1` for this outcome? Well if someone has a probability of `0.04`, we know it would have an expected outcome of `1` time after 25 trials.

Therefore the expected number of tosses to get `2` heads in a row with this unfair coin would be 25 tosses.

Now for using Markov Chains, we would have two states. An `H` state and a `T` state for heads and tails respectively. Each state would have a recursive path on themselves, since you can of course flip the same result you just flipped, and you would have a path that goes to the other option because you could also *not* flip the same result.

On the `H` state, we would have the recursive path pointing back towards itself have a value of `0.2`, because the odds of flipping another heads with this unfair coin is always `0.2`, regardless of the previous outcome because flips are independent. The path going from `H` to `T` has a value of `0.8`. On the `H` state, the recursive path would also have a value of `0.8`, because that's always the probability of flipping a `T` with this coin, and lastly the path from `T` to `H` would have a value of `0.2`.

So to visualize the Markov Chain diagram, it would look like this:

`H -> H : 0.2`

`H -> T : 0.8`

`T -> T : 0.8`

`T -> H : 0.2`

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. How would one calculate the expected number of tosses after constructing the transitions probabilities using the Markov chain?